Volatility surface PCA and SABR explanation gap
I am wondering how would the results of PCA on a volatility surface would be used differently than the SABR parameters. Given the first three components of a PCA are related to level, smile and skew, these sound a lot like the SABR parameters in the way the volatility surface movement is reduced. Why would one use PCA instead of looking at historical SABR parameters in order to understand movements in the volatility surface and generate trade ideas?

Suppose you're fortunate to have lots of history for lots of points of the surface, and you want to compare $T_0$ and $T_1$ surfaces. Choice 1: $\alpha$ changed this much, $\beta$ changed this much, and $\rho$ changed this much. Choice 2: historical PC1-3 changed this many standard deviations. Perhaps both are useful?
